# How to get IIS version through .NET

Tags: asp.net, routes, iis-5

I got web app which uses ms mvc. I'm still living in stone age - using IIS5. I'm not aware how to make URL`s clean in it (without .aspx postfix) and i do not care, cause production environment won't use 5th version. But it's irritating when testing app manually.

I need a way how to make those URL`s clean or to get version of IIS inside in app to determine if .aspx postfix is needed.

Comment: Doesn't IE stands for Internet Explorer? What did you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_SOFTWARE"], should come out as "IIS/5.1" if it's populated at all.

Comment: Thanks, i'll give it a shot. Is it possible to make IIS5 urls extensionless (without .aspx, .mvc)?